# How to interpret FB API encoding

Tags: facebook-graph-api, character-encoding, special-characters

Here is a public FB post:
http://facebook.com/556645544_10152911729090545
Note the emoji after BIG BROTHER time, and others.

Here's is query that finds that same post:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=big+brother+emoji+Scott+Eaton&type=post

That query includes:
"message": "BIG BROTHER time! \udbb9\udd38It's come

How does one interpret \udbb9\udd38 ?  This is not standard Unicode, nor is it UTF-8.  How does one translate that into the correct UTF-8, which is \uF09F\92BB ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045268/how-does-facebook-encode-emoji-in-the-json-graph-api).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook encodes Emoji using the "Google" encoding as you can see from this [table](http://www.unicode.org/%7Escherer/emoji4unicode/snapshot/full.html).

`\udbb9\udd38` is javascript escaped UTF-8, and when unescaped is `U+FE538`.

I can't see the original post to be sure, but U+FE538 corresponds to `PERSONAL COMPUTER`, which is `U+1F4BB` in "unified unicode", which looks like this emoji:

I have no idea what language you are working in, but I made a Ruby Gem called [Emojivert](https://github.com/philoye/emojivert) that assists with the conversion from Google encoding to Unified unicode.